# Cant get dom element to update variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a todolist type webpage and I ran into this problem. Basically when I change or update the list element, the list does not get updated and is still looping through the first 2 buttons in its default html

index.html:

```html
<body>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link href="styles.css">

    <div id="essentials"></div>
        <h2>ToDoList</h2>
        <input id="essentialInput">
        <button id="addTask">Add Task</button>
    </div>
    <list id="list">
        <h3 id="0">something epic <button class="deleteButton" id="0">Delete</button></h3>
        <h3 id="1">Something else <button class="deleteButton" id="1">Delete</button></h3>
    </list>
</body>
```

script.js:

```js
const essentialInput = document.getElementById('essentialInput')
const addTaskButton = document.getElementById('addTask')
const list = document.getElementById('list')
let button = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteButton')
addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    text = essentialInput.value

    if(text == null) return "Nothing in input field"

    children = list.childElementCount
    list.innerHTML += `<h3 id=${children}>${text} <button class="deleteButton" id=${children}>Delete</button></h3>`
})

for(let i = 0; i<button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(button[i].id)
    })
}
```

I know the issue but I dont know how to fix it. I've tried to put the button eventListeners in a change event listener for when the list changes but then nothing happens until I click a delete button.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `<list>` HTML element

Comment: oh...that explains that but what about my question?

Comment: i used a defer in the script linkage, which will wait for the elements in the html to be loaded before the script is loaded? or thats what i believe defer means

Comment: Ah right, I missed that. My apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using the `+=` operator on an element's `innerHTML` is **NOT** just concatenating the new HTML... It wholy replaces it with the result.

That is why you were loosing the listeners already set on the two first `<h3>`.

Then, the new `<h3>` never had any listeners on them.

So the solution for this case is to register the event listener on the *static parent* on behalf of its childrens... And take advantage of event bubbling. That is called event delegation.

```js
const essentialInput = document.getElementById('essentialInput')
const addTaskButton = document.getElementById('addTask')
const list = document.getElementById('list')
let button = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteButton')
addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    text = essentialInput.value

    if(text == null) return "Nothing in input field"

    children = list.childElementCount
    list.innerHTML += `<h3 id=${children}>${text} <button class="deleteButton" id=${children}>Delete</button></h3>`
})

// Add the event listener on the static parent
list.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target.classList.contains("deleteButton")){
    console.clear()
    console.log(e.target.id)
  }
})
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link href="styles.css">

    <div id="essentials"></div>
        <h2>ToDoList</h2>
        <input id="essentialInput">
        <button id="addTask">Add Task</button>
    </div>
    <list id="list">
        <h3 id="0">something epic <button class="deleteButton" id="0">Delete</button></h3>
        <h3 id="1">Something else <button class="deleteButton" id="1">Delete</button></h3>
    </list>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd just use `list.append()` instead of overwriting the HTML every time. Would still use event delegation though